# Error while creating dynamic box in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When i passed height as 10 and width as 20 it creates a horizondal line. I expected it to be a box of given ems. What changes should I make?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Box extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          style={{
            height: `${this.props.height}em`,
            widht: `${this.props.width}em`,
            backgroundColor: this.props.color,
          }}
        />
        <button>X</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Box;
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: You have a typo 
`widht: `${this.props.width}em`,`
This should be `width`.

Comment: Thanks. I didnt notice it. Its working now.